# HTML/CSS for Twitter widget width

Tags: html, css, widget, twitter

The code Twitter gives you to paste in the html looks like this:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/username" data-widget-id="248169276782018560">Tweets by @username</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

They allow you to set a height, which I set to 600. When placed on my site I get this (when viewing the source):

```
<iframe id="twitter-widget-6" classname="twitter-timeline twitter-timeline-rendered" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border-top-style: none; border-right-style: none; border-bottom-style: none; border-left-style: none; border-width: initial; border-color: initial; " width="220" height="600"></iframe>
```

The 220 width is what is killing me. I want the width to be the full width of the container, which is 100% (for a mobile site). Currently the 220 width goes a little more than halfway across the page and displays an ugly scrollbar.

So, why is it setting the width to 220, and how can I get it to expand to it's parent width?

Answer (score 19):

I use a responsive theme and this css code works fine. Thanks Hjuster.

```
#twitter-widget-0 { 
      width: 100% !important; 
    }
```

Comment: UPDATE JUNE 25, 2015
It seems twitter has changed the code again. This time they have set the max-width of the widget INSIDE of the iframe (i.e. on code generated from their website)

Answer (score 11):

Twitter allows you to adjust the width and height of the timeline widget via HTML width and height attributes BUT the minimum width they accept is `220 pixels` EXAMPLE: `width="220"` , `height="350"`

FROM [Twitters developers page](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#dimensions): *The minimum width of a timeline is 220px and the maximum is 520px. The minimum height is 350px*.

Answer (score 5):

You can change the width of the widget by setting its value in the "twitter-timeline" class definition, as mentioned here:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines

For example a twitter timeline widget with width 280 and height 300 is something along the lines of:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" width="280" height="300" href="https://twitter.com/YOURTWITTERUSERNAMEHERE" data-widget-id="YOURWIDGETIDHERE">Tweets by @YOURTWITTERUSERNAMEHERE</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Comment: But does that mean it'll also accept a percentage instead of an absolute width?

Comment: I tried setting a % value such as 10% for example, but doesn't seem to work as expected. Any value containing a percentage will make its width become about 500 pixels.

Answer (score 2):

```
#twitter-widget-6 {
  width:600px;
}
```

The above works, I presume the numbers correspond with how many widgets you've created.
Is the width the only thing we can change, what about fonts, I cant seems to change this?
The Twitter widget is so ugly it's hard to make it sit nicely in any layout.

Answer (score 2):

If we place below CSS, then we can set the width of the widget according to the requirement.

```
<style type="text/css"> iframe[id^='twitter-widget-']{ width:100%;} </style>
```

Answer (score 2):

if you just use

```
#twitter-widget-0 { 
    width: 100% !important; 
}
```

it will work but it will cut off on iOS devices (haven't tested on android).
To fix this, you need to add width and height to the twitter-timeline tag like so:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" width="280" height="300" href="https://twitter.com/YOURTWITTERUSERNAMEHERE" data-widget-id="YOURWIDGETIDHERE">Tweets by @YOURTWITTERUSERNAMEHERE</a>
```

Comment: This is the correct and current way to update the height. It must be on an `<a>` tag to work.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use the class twitter-timeline-rendered instead of the id #twitter-widget-0. That way, the widget is resized after rendering.

```
.twitter-timeline-rendered { 
      width: 100% !important; 
    }
```

Comment: Did you style the initial link or the rendered widget somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I have tried all above answers but no luck,

So Implemented below code myself and worked for me

```
<script type="text/javascript">

 $(window).on('load', function () {

 $('iframe[id^=twitter-widget-]').each(function () {

 var head = $(this).contents().find('head');

 if (head.length) {

 head.append('<style>.timeline { max-width: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; } .timeline .stream { max-width: none !important; width: 100% !important; }</style>');

 }

 $('#twitter-widget-0').append($('<div class=timeline>'));

 })

 });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your post, its helped me. I can accept this if another one query got cleared. $('#twitter-widget-0') here '0' static value, i want to load that value dynamically,because i have given more button, when they click more,items will load but this style is not applying to those items bcz this is statica one. so please suggest me on this.

Answer (score 1):

Include

```
data-width="100%"
```

in the anchor tags. This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `width="220"` to `width="100%"`.

Comment: Yeah, I would love to. But that is auto-generated code from twitter. They are injecting the 220 width for some reason.

Comment: right but once you've got it you can change the value this is the code they give you to paste into the page. just us any editor eg notepad to edit it

Comment: No, the first bit of code in my post is what they give you - the starts with <a class="twitter-timeline"... The second bit is what you get when you do a "view source" on the site once it's loaded.

Comment: OK I see. Off the top of my head I don't know a way round that. Best wait see if you get a response from s/o familiar with the API

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...

```
    #twitter-widget-6{
      width:600px;
    }
```

Comment: Twitter by default have a `.timeline{max-width:520px;` max width. So the iframe will be 600 px width but in the iframe the content will be 520px width. By overloading the style directly in the iframe, you redefine timeline class and you can go beyond the 520 px limit.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
.twitter-timeline {
    height: 180px !important; 
    width: 100% !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it, using almost the same logic than [Chandrakant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1343297/chandrakant) did use to insert the style in the iframe.

First of all: add twitter widget the proper way

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/loading
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
        t = window.twttr || {};
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
    js.async = true;
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    t._e = [];
    t.ready = function(f) {
        t._e.push(f);
    };
    return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>
```

Now you have a nice window.twttr._e array which may contain everything that will run once twitter widget.js is loaded.

*Note that I added js.async = true;*

Now you may in the same script or afterward do:

```
<script type=text/javascript">
// https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/events
window.twttr.events.bind('loaded', function (e) {
  e.widgets.forEach(function (widget) {
    // js to support twitter 100% if present
    $(widget).contents().find('head').append('<style>.timeline { max-width: 100% !important; width: 100% !important; }</style>');
  });
});
</script>
```

*Note that I used the jquery way to append the style at the end of the iframe head content. You can do it the classical way but it's longer.*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// ...
widget.contentDocument.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]...
// ...
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the recent update (or screw up) twitter have forced all feed widgets to show images automatically on load up no matter what options are set within twitter settings.

Now I am using their own widget feed within a html based site and want to disable the images from loading up. I don't mind having to start over and but could anyone advise me on where i might find a customisable html and js based twitter feed that won't include images.