# Can't adjust width on new Twitter widget

Tags: html, css, twitter, width

Yesterday I found that the Twitter feed widget thing on my site had disappeared. Turns out that they stopped support for the older version, so now I'm stuck with the new version. Problem is, I can't adjust the width to suit my page. The maximum width is 520px, but I want it set to 100%.

The code consists of an 'a' tag (with class, href, and other properties), and a script as seen below:

```
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

According to the Twitter documentation, I can adjust width and height by having them as properties in the 'a' tag, but like I said at the beginning, the width is limited to a maximum of 520px, and it doesn't accept percentage values at all.

If this cannot be solved, are there alternatives? I use this Twitter widget as a news feed, so if all else fails, is there a more convenient method to display news, other than manually editing the HTML of the page each time?

EDIT: Solved. You need to change the width as a style via CSS (for some reason, changing the width as a style from the 'a' tag would not work. Just find the class value of the 'a' tag, and then set the style in your CSS.

Comment: I refuse to believe you have never heard of Wordpress, or some other CMS.

Comment: All I know of Wordpress is it has something to do with blogging. I am not aware of them having a function similar to the Twitter feed, and if they do have it, I'd rather solve my original problem before looking at the alternatives, not the other way around.

Comment: What kind of comment is that, @KyleSevenoaks? Anyway, there are other Twitter feed plugins out there. We've used quite a few in here. Let me try and dig some out for you.

Comment: You might find some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539496/html-css-for-twitter-widget-width

Comment: Yes, the CSS width did the trick. Strange, though. Setting the width as a style would not work.