# Change Twitter Widget Height on Non-WP Site (New API?)

Tags: javascript, html, twitter, widget

I've tried searching these forums for an update on setting the widget height for the embedded Twitter widget (https://support.twitter.com/articles/20170071). You can designate a height in the setting fields on Twitter (they have a form to create a semi-custom widget), but it doesn't go into effect when I add it to my HTML. Most of the forum questions on here are from 2013 (a different code from Twitter?) and don't seem to work for me.

I tried this JSFiddle code:

> http:// jsfiddle.net /mandykiwi/ NbF7C/

but setting the height to !important in CSS didn't do anything for me. I may have done it wrong. I entered this into my styles.css sheet, as per the jsfiddle code:

```
.timeline .stream {
   height: 600px!important;
}
```

My HTML came from Twitter, plus some of the code they provided for further customization:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/KGShowroom" data-widget-id="631599342176989184" data-chrome="nofooter transparent noheader noborders noscrollbar" height="600">Tweets by @KGShowroom</a>
<script>
   ! function(d, s, id) {
       var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
           p = /^http:/.test(d.location) ? 'http' : 'https';
       if (!d.getElementById(id)) {
           js = d.createElement(s);
           js.id = id;
           js.src = p + "://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }
   }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs");
</script>
```

(I've also tried it without the addition to the stylesheet.)

Another forum answer here on Stackoverflow says that the height is now set within the JS code that Twitter generates ([HTML/CSS for Twitter widget width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12539496/html-css-for-twitter-widget-width#comment50644756_12722494)) but I'm not sure what that means; can it be changed?

I am not exactly sure what size I need it to be, but I know I need it larger than it is. I'm guessing 100% in height so that it can be responsive, but even doing it in px, it isn't changing.

This is the site I'm trying to work on this with: http://kgshowroom.com/test/index.html

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe.twitter-timeline {

    min-height:600px!important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NbF7C/12/  They set **min-height**, so, just override it.

Comment: I entered the code you entered above into my css, but it still didn't change the size of the Twitter widget. I'm pretty new to this stuff, so if there's something I can do to help (if there's code that I need to show), I'm happy to grab what's needed. Thanks!

Comment: Would it matter where I am placing the css code within the stylesheet...? I feel like that shouldn't matter, but thought I'd check. It's the only variable that I can see I could be missing...

Comment: Here's my page — you can see the Twitter at the bottom, in the black section: http://kgshowroom.com/test/index.html

Comment: :) Yes, i see it... 1000px, just clear cache in your browser. :)

Comment: So sorry! I cleared out the cache, cookies, browsing history, everything, in Chrome and still not seeing a change. And it shouldn't be 1000px, it should be 600px like what's in your code. Can you tell me which part of the code it's showing 1000px? Ahh! I'm so sorry this is being difficult!

Answer (score 0):

if your only need is to set a fixed height to the iframe containing the feed, you need to substitute

- height="600" 
  with
- data-height="600"

in the a-html tag.

See official configuration site, here: https://publish.twitter.com/#, and adapt your code to the result.